# How to change logo for BlueSpice MediaWiki?

Tags: mediawiki

In a vanilla MediaWiki, I would edit the `LocalSettings.php` to change the line:

```
## The relative URL path to the logo.  Make sure you change this from the default,
## or else you'll overwrite your logo when you upgrade!
$wgLogo = "$wgScriptPath/resources/assets/wiki.png";
```

However, this has no effect with BlueSpice and that wiki.png is not being used.  How can I change the logo in BlueSpice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead use the web interface at:

http://wiki.example.com/index.php?title=Special:WikiAdmin&mode=Preferences

And open the `BlueSpice` section of `Preferences` where you will see the `Logo path:` that may be filled in with a path like you would use for `$wgLogo`.